# Update columns with a information from a different dataset in tidyverse

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr, merge

I am trying to get R (`tidyverse`) to check the Country (Abbreviations are in two columns both columns need to be updated) Columns with the master list of countries and replace them with the full country name. I have tried an `ifelse` statement but am getting weird results. The data sets can be [found here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/156RqWANAu2wL-Tr-x_wsdZ_qjEgM_5jM?usp=drive_link). Any suggestions would be most helpful.

```
# head of df1 
df1 <- structure(list(CountryCode = c("BF", "BG", "BM", "BR", "CA", 
"CE", "CH", "GH", "GM", "HA", "IC", "IN", "IR", "IT", "IZ", "JO", 
"KE", "KS", "LE", "MX", "NI", "NL", "NP", "PK", "QA", "SA", "SF", 
"SP", "TC", "TD", "TU", "TW", "UK", "US", "VM", "JA", "EI"), 
    CountryName = c("BAHAMAS, THE", "BANGLADESH", "MYANMAR", 
    "BRAZIL", "CANADA", "SRI LANKA", "CHINA", "GHANA", "GERMANY", 
    "HAITI", "ICELAND", "INDIA", "IRAN", "ITALY", "SYRIA", "JORDAN", 
    "KENYA", "KOREA, REPUBLIC OF (SOUTH )", "LEBANON", "MEXICO", 
    "NIGERIA", "NETHERLANDS, THE", "NEPAL", "PAKISTAN", "QATAR", 
    "SAUDI ARABIA", "SOUTH AFRICA", "SPAIN", "UNITED ARAB EMIRATES", 
    "TRINIDAD AND TOBAGO", "TURKEY", "CHINA (TAIWAN)", "UNITED KINGDOM", 
    "UNITED STATES", "VIETNAM", "JAPAN", "IRELAND")), row.names = c(NA, 
-37L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# df2 (with the NAs removed)
df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("E23531197", "Q07441087", "U79148472", 
"Y43292349", "A40257720", "Y64624318", "B97628594", "T06694322", 
"J67643839", "B11219391", "V72937405", "C22564030", "B90485180", 
"B56635832", "J44870077", "Y05510846", "X82045887", "V14380989", 
"J87108024", "X61041595", "A60573885", "Y23860927", "T74687928", 
"G60127163", "P45475749", "D40096957", "F73581752", "M76164536", 
"X57076671", "K30511805", "B41693626", "E50532024", "H47908538"
), `MA Nation` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "IN", 
NA, NA, "CA", NA, NA, NA, NA), `PR Nation` = c("PK", "BG", "MX", 
"PK", "IN", "CH", "JA", "EI", "UK", "CH", "UK", "IN", "TU", "BG", 
"IN", "CA", "CA", "PK", "CH", "BG", "LE", "IN", "IN", "TW", "BG", 
"IN", "CH", "BG", "CA", "BF", "CH", "CH", "CH")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -33L))
```

Comment: Hi asokol. 1) Please edit the question into include what you've tried, including a description of whatever is wrong (especially if it isn't an error message). 2) Do you know the source of the country codes in the lookup table? 3) Is it important to retain the order of rows in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2 |> 
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "Type", values_to = "CountryCode", values_drop_na = TRUE)|>
  left_join(df1) |> 
  select(-CountryCode) |> 
  pivot_wider(values_from = "CountryName")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 33 × 3
   ID        `PR Nation`    `MA Nation`
   <chr>     <chr>          <chr>      
 1 E23531197 PAKISTAN       NA         
 2 Q07441087 BANGLADESH     NA         
 3 U79148472 MEXICO         NA         
 4 Y43292349 PAKISTAN       NA         
 5 A40257720 INDIA          NA         
 6 Y64624318 CHINA          NA         
 7 B97628594 JAPAN          NA         
 8 T06694322 IRELAND        NA         
 9 J67643839 UNITED KINGDOM NA         
10 B11219391 CHINA          NA         
# ℹ 23 more rows
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for responding; I will give it a try. What to the vertical bars do?

Comment: @asokol you mean the `|>`s? They're the native pipes, same as `%>%`, but you don't need to load a library :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` the two data frames by country code.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

df <- read_xlsx('~Data SU23 Enroll R AY22-23 2023-08-23 2 Stack Overflow.xlsx')
countrydata <- read_xlsx('~TBL Country codes.xlsx')

glimpse(df)
#> Rows: 542
#> Columns: 3
#> $ ID          <chr> "F31769765", "E23531197", "Q07441087", "Y92280507", "F2688…
#> $ `MA Nation` <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ `PR Nation` <chr> NA, "PK", "BG", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "M…
glimpse(countrydata)
#> Rows: 37
#> Columns: 2
#> $ CountryCode <chr> "BF", "BG", "BM", "BR", "CA", "CE", "CH", "GH", "GM", "HA"…
#> $ CountryName <chr> "BAHAMAS, THE", "BANGLADESH", "MYANMAR", "BRAZIL", "CANADA…

df %>%
  # Put all columns with country codes in a long layout
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  # Join with the country code table
  left_join(countrydata,
            by = join_by(value == CountryCode)) %>%
  # Drop the country code column
  select(-value) %>%
  # Return to the two country columns layout
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,
              values_from = CountryName) %>%
  # Append the rows for IDs without country data
  bind_rows(df %>% filter(is.na(`PR Nation`) & is.na(`MA Nation`)))
#> # A tibble: 542 × 3
#>    ID        `PR Nation`    `MA Nation`
#>    <chr>     <chr>          <chr>      
#>  1 E23531197 PAKISTAN       <NA>       
#>  2 Q07441087 BANGLADESH     <NA>       
#>  3 U79148472 MEXICO         <NA>       
#>  4 Y43292349 PAKISTAN       <NA>       
#>  5 A40257720 INDIA          <NA>       
#>  6 Y64624318 CHINA          <NA>       
#>  7 B97628594 JAPAN          <NA>       
#>  8 T06694322 IRELAND        <NA>       
#>  9 J67643839 UNITED KINGDOM <NA>       
#> 10 B11219391 CHINA          <NA>       
#> # ℹ 532 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi Seth, Thank you for responding. I will try your approach. I need to keep the NAs in the dataset because of what I am using them for.